# decoding int8 array to a utf-8 string

Tags: python

if i have a array of int8 like this:

```
array('b', [-20, -107, -124, -21, -123, -107])
```

and i want to decode this array to utf-8 character

for example the array above is `\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95` in hex (Its Korean)

what would be the best approach of solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.tobytes`:

```
>>> from array import array
>>> arr = array('b', [-20, -107, -124, -21, -123, -107])
>>> arr.tobytes()
b'\xec\x95\x84\xeb\x85\x95'
```

And to a `str`, you just decode the bytes:

```
>>> arr.tobytes().decode()
'아녕'
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! didnt work python 2.7 but i just found out tostring().decode("utf-8") works but still ty!